# jQuery Tabs - opening from another page

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble opening a tab from a link on a different page. 
Using jQuery tabs and apparently the link to the first tab opens fine, but the rest don't.

My css

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="selected"><a href="#tab-1">One</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#tab-2">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-4">four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
          <div class="inner">
        <div class="one">
          <div class="wrap block-3 border-1"> 
                             <p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
```

Link from the another page:

```
<p><a href="business.html#tab-1" class="button-2">one</a>  </p>
<p><a href="business.html#tab-2" class="button-2">two</a>  </p>
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: post your js code here too

Answer (score 0):

The [EasyTabs plugin](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) handles this quite nicely with the hashchange plugin. Are you using a plugin or rolling your own?

Comment: wasnt using a plugin.. I tried what charlie mentioned, but doesnt seem to work :S

Answer (score 0):

Following will parse the hash and subtract 1 from the number to get the starting tab index. If there is no hash, will default to first tab

```
var hash= location.hash, startTab=0;
if( hash && hash.indexOf('-')>-1){
  startTab= parseInt( hash.split('-').pop() -1, 10) || 0;
}

$('#tabs').tabs({ active: startTab});
```

See `active` option in docs:  http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

**EDIT:**

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6s2Rv/

Comment: tried that, but somehow it doesnt still work except for the 1st tab.

Comment: works fine in console on jQueryUI demo page. Do hashes match the href of tabs? The ones shown above seem to . Try `alert(  startTab)` to see what it returns. If familiar with console is better to log to console and checc hash and startTab values

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but i think phrased the question the wrong way. What I am trying to do is navigate to different tabs on one page from links on another.  So if i click link A on page 1, tab 1 will open on page 2. If I click link B on page 1, tab 2 will open on page 2...

Comment: right.. this is what my code is for... to parse hash from url...just add hash to links in other pages..as shown in your href's